# How to import javascript code both on the client and on the server side when using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I have a couple of Javascript functions I need to use both on the server side and on the client side in a node application.

On the server side, I could create a module and `require` it. I would need to `module.exports` my functions. Unfortunately, I could not use that code module on the client side, because there is no such thing as `require` on the client side.

I don't want to maintain the (nearly) same code in two version of the files. Is there a standard/safe way to import Javascript code in a node module? I mean literally, without using `require` and `module.exports`? Or is there another solution to my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [browserify](http://browserify.org/), which lets you run Node-tyle modules with `require()` and `module.exports` in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I have used browserify in the past. It allows you to use common.js style require syntax on the client side. A word of warning, you will probably have to use a single client side entry point, and therefore re-write a lot of your client side code.

Here's the link - [borwserify](http://browserify.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've seen Ember implement its own require method but I can't find any documentation for it.

On the way I saw http://www.requirejs.org which creates its own new require method which works which both the browser and nodejs.